# How to run multiple command with single command in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, zsh

For example, i have to run 4 command to start my project.

1. Django server
2. Redis-server
3. React server
4. Python qcluster

How i start this 4 things with single command in linux.

I have to start manually all thing's, when i start working on project.

Comment: Making an `alias`  may go a long way - It'll still be four commands, but you'll only have to type one instruction.

Comment: You want to run sequentially ?  then `echo 1 &&   echo 2 &&  echo 3 &&   echo 5` if in parallel `echo 1;  echo 2 ;  echo 3 ;   echo 5`

Comment: Or just put the commands in a text file, one per-line, and make it executable (`chmod +x`) and you have yourself a script (include the `#!/bin/sh`, or `#!/bin/zsh` or whatever interpreter you need as the first line) If the filename was `server_start`, then you would run it with `./server_start`. You probably want to add error checking so it outputs a message if a command fails.

Comment: Btw, are you using [tag:bash] or [tag:zsh]? You've tagged both which is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `;` in most linux shells to execute multiple commands in a single statement:

```
Django server; Redis-server; React server; Python qcluster
```

You can also create an alias for it, so it will be easier to call. Save below in your .profile, or wherever you save your aliases:

```
alias startup_cmd='Django server; Redis-server; React server; Python qcluster'
```

Now you can simply use `startup_cmd` anywhere to execute these 4 commands.